# Laravel Backpack 4.0. Save a model then another one (different)

Tags: laravel, laravel-backpack

In my laravel/backpack 4.0 project I have three model:

```
Product:   id, name, ...
Pricebook: id, name, ...
Price:     id, pricebook_id, value, ...
```

I need to create a row in prices table every time a new Product is stored id database.
Is there a method like 'before' or 'after' save to hook?
if not, any other solution?

Answer (score 2):

...I got confused about something trivial, probably a mispelling. This is the solution thank's Martin

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers\Admin;

use App\Http\Requests\ProductRequest;
use Backpack\CRUD\app\Http\Controllers\CrudController;
use Backpack\CRUD\app\Library\CrudPanel\CrudPanelFacade as CRUD;
use App\Models\Price;

class ProductCrudController extends CrudController
{
    use \Backpack\CRUD\app\Http\Controllers\Operations\ListOperation;
    use \Backpack\CRUD\app\Http\Controllers\Operations\CreateOperation {store as traitStore ;}
    use \Backpack\CRUD\app\Http\Controllers\Operations\UpdateOperation;
    use \Backpack\CRUD\app\Http\Controllers\Operations\DeleteOperation;
    use \Backpack\CRUD\app\Http\Controllers\Operations\ShowOperation;

    public function store()
    {
        $request = $this->crud->validateRequest();
        $response = $this->traitStore();

        //get last inserted row id
        $entryID = $this->data['entry']->id;

        $price = new Price();
        $price->product_id = $entryID;
        $price->price = 0;
        $price->save();

        // show a success message
        \Alert::success('New price created in DEFAULT_BASE_PRICEBOOK'))->flash();

        return $response;
    }

    ...
```

Answer (score 1):

There are no such hooks, but you can override these methods that control the database insert/update. From the documentation:

> Callbacks
>   Developers coming from GroceryCRUD on CodeIgniter or other CRUD systems will be looking for callbacks to run before_insert, before_update, after_insert, after_update. There are no callbacks in Backpack. The store() and update() code is inside a trait, so you can easily overwrite that method, and call it inside your new method. For example, here's how we can do things before/after an item is saved in the Create operation:

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers\Admin;

use Backpack\CRUD\app\Http\Controllers\CrudController;

class ProductCrudController extends CrudController
{
    use \Backpack\CRUD\app\Http\Controllers\Operations\CreateOperation { store as traitStore; }

    // ...

    public function store()
    {
      // do something before validation, before save, before everything
      $response = $this->traitStore();
      // do something after save
      return $response;
    }
```

[Source](https://backpackforlaravel.com/docs/4.0/getting-started-crud-operations)

Comment: Thank you Martin, this is the first part of what I need... the second part is: How can I create a pricerow? I can't build a new Model/Price(), App/Model/Price is outside of this namespace...

Comment: @GiordoG why couldn't you? You can instantiate classes from other namespaces: use App\Model\Price; $price = new Price();

Comment: Sorry I'am a newbie, what did you mean?
the error message said: 'App\Http\Controllers\Admin\Model\Price' does not exist 
Price model is at 'App/Models/Price ...

Comment: First of, namespaces are using backslash \  -- You probably mean that the App/Model/Price.php file? What is namespace of that file?

Comment: If you have no idea what I am talking about, post the Price model here and let me see